# For Loop with If Conditions to Return Non-NA Values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a simple for loop with if statements to get non-NA values, however, receiving an error. Could you help?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Platform ID' : [1,2,3,4], "Delivery Date" : [str(2009), float("nan"), float("nan"), float("nan")],
                                              "Build Year" : [float("nan"),str(2009),float("nan"), float("nan")], 
                                              "In Service Date" : [float("nan"),float("nan"), str("14-11-2009"), float("nan")]})
df.dtypes
df
```

```
def delivery_year(delivery_year, build_year, service_year):
    out = []
    for i in range(0,len(delivery_year)):
        if any(delivery_year.notna()):
            out[i].append(delivery_year)
        if any(delivery_year[i].isna() and build_year[i].notna()):
            out[i].append(build_year)
        elif any(build_year[i].isna()):
            out[i].append(service_year.str.strip().str[-4:])
        else:
            out[i].append(float("nan"))
    return out

df["Delivery Year"] = delivery_year(df["Delivery Date"], df["Build Year"], df["In Service Date"])
```

Error Message:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Could you share your error message please ? :)

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @JaroslavKotrba what is the logic and expected output?

Comment: I want to get a new column with Delivery Year, it consists of these columns, however, there are a lot of Nans so the logic is that the for loop goes through columns and returns the first non-Na value. The best-case scenario is Delivery Date, when this is not there then Build Year if even this is not there then at least In Service Date when the machine was set into work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be to use `np.where()` statement :

```
import numpy as np

df["Delivery Year"] = np.where(df['Delivery Date'].notna(),df['Delivery Date'],np.where(df['Build Year'].notna(),df['Build Year'],np.where(df['In Service Date'].notna(),df['In Service Date'].str.strip().str[-4:],float("nan"))))
```

Like this, your are going in the reverse side, when it's not null, take it, otherwise switch to another solution

```
np.where( IF, THEN, ELSE )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) however, I would like to have a for loop with ifs statements!

Comment: For loops are really time consuming and not usefull at all in your example.

Comment: I mean, I like your example, however, I would modify the for loop later on for different scenarios :)

Comment: For some reason it does not work for a bigger dataset :(

Comment: Can't help you without providing the error message

Comment: It is not an error message but it takes the whole date and not only the year in the last column... it works in the test table correctly. I would love to have the for a loop.